# Google Chrome hangs for regex

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

I have a regex `^([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]*)([\.\_]?[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,6})+(\/[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]+)*$`.

It is regex for validation of Domain.

It works fine for most of the domain but page hangs for below string:

> "**webmail.google.com.qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq.......**"

It works fine in Firefox and throws validation error message but same thing makes page hangs in Google Chrome. I can't find the proper solution for it. I tried on all other regex sites also but couldn't find exact solution.

Comment: I don't know why this question is being closed. The question is quite clear that the regex causes problem, and it is asking for solution.

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using? The code hangs on FF 32 Windows 32-bit version, though.

Comment: Actually the page hangs in Chrome but not in firefox. In firefox, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed catastrophic backtracking, and it is caused by `[\.\_]?` being optional, and `([\.\_]?[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*` degenerates to `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)*` on specific input.

Removing the optional quantifier `([\.\_][A-Za-z0-9-]+)*` should resolve the problem. The power of the regex stays the same. `.` and `_` doesn't need escaping inside character class, so you can write `[._]` without changing the meaning of the regex.

As long as an implementation returns correct result according to the specification, it is free to optimize the matching process and reduces the run time for classic catastrophic pattern. As for why Chrome hangs on this regex and Firefox doesn't, Firefox has been exhibiting this behavior for quite some time. I'm not quite sure of the details, though. (From which version did they overhaul the engine? Can the result be trusted or does it exit early? How does it prevent the backtracking? What is the scope of the optimization? etc.).